# Installation Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, partitioning, permissions, gparted

I am a new Ubuntu user. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop's hard drive which was completely empty without partitions. When installing I could not define partitions or by selecting *Options* that indicates that it does allow partitions.

The installation finished and it used the entire disk. I tried to change the partition using GParted, but it didn't permit me to do it . I tried to use 'KDE Partition Manager' and I couldn't use it either because I didn't have administrative permissions.

Can someone tell me what to do?

1. How to uninstall Ubuntu? or
2. How to modify a partition? and
3. How can I get administrative permissions in Ubuntu?

After Ubuntu is running OK, I intend to use VirtualBox to install Windows 7.

Comment: you can use grub to use windows7 and if you want to install it on other partition you should make a partition using g parted and run it as root user.

Comment: Boot from USB/DVD select try Ubuntu. You are now using a virtual file system your HDD is not mounted.  You can now use Gparted to resize partitions etc.

Answer (score 0):

GParted should work. It will ask you to give your password. It can only resize an unmounted partition, so you will have to unmount the partition (GParted can do that) then resize it, then remount it.

There are good descriptions of the process here: <[How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)>